# Regular expression replace in MariaDB

Tags: regex, mariadb, regexp-replace, mariadb-10.3

I am trying to match internal links in an SMF forum and convert the BBC tag from **url** to **iurl** so that a link like this:

`[url=https://www.translatum.gr/forum/index.php?topic=989144.0]κατ' ἐπιταγήν -> by way of command[/url]`

Will become:

`[iurl=https://www.translatum.gr/forum/index.php?topic=989144.0]κατ' ἐπιταγήν -> by way of command[/iurl]`

I have tried something like this on PhpMyAdmin (using MariaDB 10.3)

```sql
UPDATE smf_messages
SET body = REGEXP_REPLACE(body, 
    '(\[url=https:\/\/www\.translatum\.gr)(.*?)(\[\/url\])', 
    '[iurl=https://www.translatum.gr\\2[/iurl]
  ')
WHERE ID_TOPIC = 987873
```

which although appears to work on a [test in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yKPwZc/1) gives garbage output on SQL (i.e. it is replaced with multiple iterations of the link and its text). I have used [this for syntax reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double escape the backslash in the string literal to actually define the literal backslash char that forms *regex escapes*.

Also, your regex replacement is too redundant, you may capture more text and make your replacement even shorter:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(body, '\\[(url=https://www\\.translatum\\.gr.*?)\\[/url]', '[i\\1[/iurl]')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yKPwZc/2).

Comment: Wow, amazing, multiple escapes get me confused :) Pity that regex101 does not have a MySQL flavor.